# How to create a Heptacube using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, dimensions

I'm trying to create a Heptacube or a [7-dimensional cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycube) in Blender. This would not be easy to model so I used [Chat GPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt/)'s codex to give me the vertices, edges, and faces of a Heptacube and all the code for Python. Every time I go to execute the code Blender crashes since I'm using vertices with 7 dimensions, but of course Blender only supports 3-dimensional vertices and thus crashes. How can to rewrite the script to represent the Heptacube in 3 dimensional space?

I have 128gb of dd4 an i9 and a 3090ti so not a hardware issue. Here's the script.

```
import bpy
vertices = [
    (1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
    (1,1,1,1,1,1,-1),
    (1,1,1,1,-1,1,1),
    (1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (1,1,-1,1,1,1,1),
    (1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1),
    (1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1),
    (1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,1,1,1,1,1),
    (1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1),
    (1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1),
    (1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1),
    (1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
    (-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,1,1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1),
    (-1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1),
    (1,1,1,-1,1,1,1),
    (1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1),
    (1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1),
    (1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1),
    (1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1),
    (1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1),
    (-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1),
    (-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1),
    (-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1),
    (-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1)
]

edges = [
(0,1),
(0,2),
(0,4),
(0,8),
(1,3),
(1,5),
(1,9),
(2,3),
(2,6),
(2,10),
(3,7),
(3,11),
(4,5),
(4,6), 
(4,12),
(5,7),
(5,13),
(6,7),
(6,14),
(7,15),
(8,9),
(8,10),
(8,12),
(9,11),
(9,13),
(10,11),
(10,14),
(11,15),
(12,13),
(12,14),
(13,15), 
(14,15),
(16,17),
(16,18),
(16,20),
(17,19),
(17,21), 
(18,19),
(18,22),
(19,23), 
(20,21),
(20,22),
(21,23),
(22,23),
(24,25),
(24,26), 
(24,28),
(25,27),
(25,29),
(26,27),
(26,30),
(27,31),
(28,29),
(28,30),
(29,31),
(30,31),
(32,33),
(32,34),
(32,36),
(33,35),
(33,37),
(34,35),
(34,38),
(35,39),
(36,37),
(36,38), 
(37,39),
(38,39),
(40,41),
(40,42),
(40,44),
(41,43),
(41,45),
(42,43),
(42,46),
(43,47),
(44,45),
(44,46),
(45,47),
(46,47),
(48,49),
(48,50),
(48,52),
(49,51),
(49,53),
(50,51),
(50,54),
(51,55),
(52,53), 
(52,54),
(53,55),
(54,55),
(56,57),
(56,58),
(56,60),
(57,59), 
(57,61),
(58,59),
(58,62),
(59,63),
(60,61), 
(60,62),
(61,63), 
(62,63)
]

# Define the faces of the heptacube
faces = [
(0,1,3,2),
(0,2,6,4),
(0,4,12,8),
(1,5,7,3),
(1,9,11,7),
(2,3,7,6),
(2,6,14,10),
(3,7,11,15),
(4,5,13,12), 
(4,6,14,12),
(5,7,15,13),
(8,9,11,10),
(8,10,14,12),
(9,11,15,13),
(10,14,15,11),
(16,17,19,18),
(16,18,22,20),
(17,21,23,19),
(18,19,23,22),
(20,21,23,22),
(24,25,27,26),
(24,26,30,28),
(25,29,31,27),
(26,27,31,30),
(28,29,31,30),
(32,33,35,34),
(32,34,38,36),
(33,37,39,35),
(34,35,39,38),
(36,37,39,38), 
(40,41,43,42),
(40,42,46,44),
(41,45,47,43),
(42,43,47,46),
(44,45,47,46),
(48,49,51,50),
(48,50,54,52),
(49,53,55,51),
(50,51,55,54),
(52,53,55,54),
(56,57,59,58),
(56,58,62,60), 
(57,61,63,59),
(58,59,63,62),
(60,61,63,62)
]

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("heptacube")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("heptacube", mesh)

bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)

mesh.from_pydata(vertices, edges, faces)
```

Comment: can u explain me, why one vertex has 7 values in your code?

Comment: My bad! I am new to python and am just trying to get a 3-dimensional representation of a hepteract. Chat GPT seems to have given me the coordinates for 7-dimensional space.

Comment: It is not possible to directly represent a 7-cube or hepteract in 3-dimensional space, as it is a 7-dimensional object. However, you can use various techniques in Blender to visualize the 7-cube in a way that is more accessible to 3-dimensional visualization.

One way to do this is to use the projection method to create a 3-dimensional representation of the 7-cube. This involves projecting the 7-dimensional vertices of the 7-cube onto a 3-dimensional plane, which results in a distorted but more easily understandable representation of the 7-cube.

Comment: Hi @Doc I changed the title to "How to create a Heptacube using Python" because we already know why blender crashes due to the incorrect usage of blender vertices wherein blender only supports 3 dimensions. So our goal now is to find out how to rewrite the script to represent the 7 dimensional heptacube in 3D space using python.

Comment: For nD to mD conversions, normally you'll need a Matrix that represents the transformation that you want to apply, and multiply  all vertices positions with that matrix. It's the same process as when you calculate screen positions (2D) of a vertex in 3D space, thought your matrix for 7D has to be bigger than the typical 4x4 matrix of the screen projection (you can see from the 3D to 2D example, that there are infinite matrices you can use).